# asprintf - when to use free()?

Tags: c, free

[asprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) says

> The functions asprintf() and vasprintf() are analogs of sprintf(3) and
>   vsprintf(3), except that they allocate a string large enough to hold
>   the output including the terminating null byte, and return a pointer
>   to it via the first argument. **This pointer should be passed to free(3)
>   to release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.**

Here is my C code

```
void function(){
    char *out = NULL;
    int parts[16] = {1,2,05,003};
    asprintf(&out, "%d.%d.%d.%d", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
  //  free(out);
}

int main(void){
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

When the function is monitored on the debug mode, I see that the variable is already destroyed when it returns from the function. Why I don't need to `free()` the code above?

Could you tell me in what cases of `asprintf` I need to use free?

btw, I have "gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)"

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, what you did right there was create a nifty memory leak.

Comment: You do not understand the concept of dynamic memory. Read a bit more and rethink what you have done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to call `free()`.

The variable leaves the scope, so the actual *value* of the variable (the address that `free()` needs) is lost at that point, creating a memory leak.

The `free()` function is interested in the address of memory previously returned by `malloc()`  or some other heap allocation call, not at all in your particular variable.

You could do:

```
char *out = NULL, *a, *b, *c, *d, *e;
int parts[16] = {1,2,05,003};
asprintf(&out, "%d.%d.%d.%d", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
a = b = c = d = e = out;
```

and that's just five more variables holding copies of the same address going out of scope. The heap subsystem (as reached through the `malloc()`/`free()` calls) knows nothing about this, of course.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you don't quite understand what pointers are, what local variables are, and what allocating memory does.

In your `function()` you have a variable `out`. You've declared that it is a char pointer.

You're passing a pointer to *that variable* to `asprintf()`.  This is so `asprintf` can allocate some memory on the heap, and store the address of that memory location in `out`. This is called a "pointer to a pointer" and why the signature of `asprintf()` appears as `asprintf(char **ret, .. )` - note the double `**`

`out` now contains the address of the allocated memory. You then leave `function()`. `out` ceases to exist because it's a local variable and only exists on the stack. The *address* that was previously contained in it is lost but the memory that was allocated on the heap that address referred to remains allocated ... and you have a memory leak.

You need to `free()` that memory before you lose the address and it becomes forever beyond your reach.

Answer (score 5):

> Could you tell me in what cases of asprintf I need to use free?

Every time, except when `asprintf` returns -1.

> If memory allocation wasn't possible, or some other error occurs, these functions will return -1, and **the contents of `strp` is undefined**.

You can analyze *valgrind* ouput for instance.

- Without `free` call:

> ==3711== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==3711==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
>   ==3711==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 108 bytes allocated

Obviously, there is a memory leak.

- With `free` call:

> ==3722== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==3722==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==3722==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 108 bytes allocated

Answer (score 4):

`out` is "destroyed", but not what is was pointing to. The latter is still allocated, but any reference to it is lost. You can consider this a memory leak.

To avoid such call `free(out)` before leaving `function()`.

An alternative solution would be to return the value of `out`from `function`, so the caller could still use the memory referenced. On the other hand the caller also then takes the responsibility to free the this memory:

```
char * function(void) {
    char * out = NULL;
    int parts[16] = {1, 2, 05, 003};

    asprintf(&out, "%d.%d.%d.%d", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);

    return out;
}

int main(void) {
    char * out = function();
    if (NULL != out)
    {
      printf("5s\n", out);
      free(out);
      out = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```